# Autorotation of CALayer on iPhone rotation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I have a UIViewController where I am adding a CALayer subclass to the view's layer:

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:myObject.backgroundLayer];
```

When I rotate the device, the view rotates, but the CALayer doesn't. It sort of gets shunted off to the left, still in portrait view.

Is there a way to make sublayers rotate automatically or do I need to apply a transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manage the rotation of the CALayer yourself. I believe that 0,0 stays at the same place and that the size is changed to match the new orientation, so if you wanted to do something yourself, you'd need to manage the addition of the rotation transformation yourself.

Answer (score 5):

With Swift 4 / iOS 11, according to your needs, you may choose one of the **6 following examples** in order to manage your `CALayer` / `CAGradientLayer` frame upon a device rotation.

The examples below use `CAGradientLayer` but can easily be mapped to `CALayer` or `CAShapeLayer` cases.

---

#### #1. Overriding `UIViewController` `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.colors = [
            UIColor.blue.cgColor,
            UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        ]
        return layer
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {         
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
    }

}
```

---

#### #2. Overriding `UIViewController` `loadView()`, subclassing `UIView` and overriding `UIView` `layoutSubviews()`

*LayerView.swift*

```
import UIKit

class LayerView: UIView {

    lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.colors = [
            UIColor.blue.cgColor,
            UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        ]
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        return layer
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

}
```

*LayerView.swift (alternative)*

```
import UIKit

class LayerView: UIView {

    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if gradientLayer == nil {
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [
                UIColor.blue.cgColor,
                UIColor.cyan.cgColor
            ]
            self.gradientLayer = gradientLayer
            layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        }

        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let layerView = LayerView()

    override func loadView() {
        view = layerView
    }

}
```

---

#### #3. Using Key Value Observing (KVO)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.colors = [
            UIColor.blue.cgColor,
            UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        ]
        return layer
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        observation = view.observe(\.frame, options: [.new], changeHandler: { [unowned self] (object: UIView, change: NSKeyValueObservedChange<CGRect>) in
            guard let frame = change.newValue else { return }
            self.gradientLayer.frame = frame
        })

        // Also works
        /*
        observation = observe(\.view.frame, options: [.new], changeHandler: { [unowned self] (object: ViewController, change: NSKeyValueObservedChange<CGRect>) in
            guard let frame = change.newValue else { return }
            self.gradientLayer.frame = frame
        })
        */
    }

}
```

---

#### #4. Overriding `UIViewController` `loadView()`, subclassing `UIView` and overriding `UIView` `layerClass`

*LayerView.swift*

```
import UIKit

class LayerView: UIView {

    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    required init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        guard let gradientLayer = layer as? CAGradientLayer else { return }
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor.blue.cgColor,
            UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        ]
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let layerView = LayerView()

    override func loadView() {
        view = layerView
    }

}
```

---

#### #5. Overriding `UIViewController` `loadView()`, subclassing `UIView` and overriding `CALayerDelegate` `layoutSublayers(of:)`

*LayerView.swift*

```
import UIKit

class LayerView: UIView {

    required init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor.blue.cgColor,
            UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        ]

        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        layer.sublayers?.forEach {
            $0.frame = layer.bounds
        }
    }

}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let layerView = LayerView()

    override func loadView() {
        view = layerView
    }

}
```

---

#### #6. Overriding `UIViewController` `loadView()`, subclassing `UIView`, overriding `UIView` `layerClass`, subclassing `CALayer` and overriding `CALayer` `layoutSublayers()`

*Layer.swift*

```
import UIKit

class Layer: CALayer {

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor.blue.cgColor,
            UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        ]

        addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSublayers() {
        sublayers?.forEach {
            $0.frame = bounds
        }
    }

}
```

*LayerView.swift*

```
import UIKit

class LayerView: UIView {

    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return Layer.self
    }

}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let layerView = LayerView()

    override func loadView() {
        view = layerView
    }

}
```

---

Sources:

- [medium.com](https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/calayer-and-auto-layout-with-swift-21b2d2b8b9d1)
- [github.com](https://github.com/imanoupetit/RotateGradients)
- [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayerdelegate/2097257-layoutsublayers)

Comment: You have some mistakes in your code…if you override a function, what do you have to do first thing? … Call super